# Count Consecutive Numeric values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

There are already many existing questions about this scenario, however I am unable to replicate the answers in my scenario.

I have a following sample Data Set:

```
ID Number  | Values 
754321       0
754321       0
754321       0
754321       0
754321       1
754321       0
754321       1
754321       0
754321       2
754321       0
754329       3
754329       4
754329       5
754329       6
754329       7
754329       8
754329       9
```

I want the SQL query that outputs the `ID Number` with the number of times the value of "0" appears consecutively. So, for the above table  I would like to get the output as follows:

```
ID Number  Count of Consecutive 0 Values
754321     4
```

Comment: What do you mean consecutive? How are the values ordered?

Comment: better to keep an incremented integer for a valid row (assuming no time data), than to insert the row x times and count it every time.

Comment: Values are ordered by date.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: There's no date here

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can assign each `0` a group by counting the number of non-zero values before it.  Then aggregate.

However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering.  Let me assume you have one.  Then:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             sum(values <> 0) over (partition by idnumber order by <ordering col>) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where values = 0
group by idnumber, grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a version of MySQL that doesn't support window functions, you can implement this functionality using variables:

```
SELECT `ID Number`, MAX(cnt) AS `Max Consecutive 0 Values`
FROM (SELECT `ID Number`, SUM(`Values` = 0) AS cnt
      FROM (SELECT `ID Number`, `Values`,
                   @cnz:= CASE WHEN `Values` != 0 THEN @cnz + 1
                               ELSE @cnz
                          END AS cnz
            FROM data
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnz := 0) init
            ORDER BY date
            ) c
      GROUP BY `ID Number`, cnz) s
GROUP BY `ID Number`
```

Output

```
ID Number   Max Consecutive 0 Values
754321      4
754329      0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d625b9/7)