# Count the total number of times the sale was consecutive for a product - Sybase IQ

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I am using Sybase IQ, and from my data set, I need to count the total number of times the sale was consecutively 10 items.

Please review the data set.

```
Product Date        Sale
Jams    2020-01-05  10
Jams    2020-01-06  10
Jams    2020-01-07  10
Jams    2020-01-08  10
Jams    2020-01-09  10
Jams    2020-01-10  1
Jams    2020-01-11  0
Jams    2020-01-12  4
Jams    2020-01-13  5
Candy   2020-01-14  3
Candy   2020-01-15  2
Candy   2020-01-16  0
Candy   2020-01-17  1
Candy   2020-01-18  0
Candy   2020-01-19  1
Candy   2020-01-20  1
Candy   2020-01-21  1
Candy   2020-01-22  4
Candy   2020-01-23  2
```

From my Data Set, I need the following output:

```
Product  Count of Consecutive 10's
Jam         5 
Candy       0
```

I have read the `SybaseIQ` help guide and tried to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ([PARTITION BY window partition] ORDER BY window ordering)` analytical function, but I keep getting a syntax error. I think the issue is that I am not able to understand the concept behind this calculation.

I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count Consecutive Numeric values in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760157/count-consecutive-numeric-values-in-sql)

Comment: This is the same as your earlier question, just replace `Values = 0` in those solutions with `Sale = 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  For each product, you can identify groups of adjacent matching rows by counting the number of non-10s before that row.  This identifies the groups.

```
select name, sum(case when sale = 10 then 1 else 0 end0 as cnt
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when sale <> 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by product order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by name,
      (case when sale <> 10 then 1 else 0 end),
      grp;
```

This returns the value for *all* groups.  I think you might want the longest, which would be:

```
select name, max(cnt)
from (select name, sum(case when sale = 10 then 1 else 0 end0 as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when sale <> 10 then 1 else 0 end)
                       over (partition by product
                             order by date
                             rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                            ) as grp
            from t
           ) t
      group by name,
               (case when sale <> 10 then 1 else 0 end),
               grp
     ) t
group by name;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for your response.  I have tried the second version, however i am getting a syntax error  "Order By Key must be numeric in Range Window Frame". If I remove the "order by date" code then the query runs, but produces an incorrect output.  Let me know what am I missing here. Thank you again for your help

Comment: @HasenCH . . . A `rows` window frame definition should fix that.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your help. Much appreciated. I actually tried a cast function on the date and converted it into numeric type and it started working accurately.

Comment: @HasenCH . . . The SQL standard specifies `range between unbounded preceding and current row` when no window frame is specified.  Some databases have limited support for `range`, resulting in an error like this.  Arrrgg!